# LFS Kernel Panic on first boot

Tags: kernel-panic, lfs

I recently finally finished my build of LinuxFromScratch version 7.9-SYSTEMD. There is one change I had to make from the book. I needed to aquire a patch for the package `inettools` that caused `PATH_PROCNET_DEV` to be undefined. Besdides that, my LFS build is on a second hard drive and will be booting independently from the host system. I am running Ubuntu 16.06 in VMWare and the LFS target machine is also ion VMWare. After the kernel starts to load it goes into a panic state saying:

```
[  10.063526] ---[ end Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)
```

I have already check whether or not the fs type and hard disk type are enabled in the kernel, rebuilt, and still to no avail. Is there anything I have missed in trying to fix this?

EDIT: Changing the hard disk type from SCSI to SATA did not work, nor did changing it to IDE

EDIT: This is my current grub.cfg file:

```
set default=0
set timeout=5
insmod ext2
set root=(hd0,gpt2)

menuentry "LinuxFromScratch-7.9-SYSTEMD" {
    linux /boot/vmlinuz-current-lfs-7.9-systemd root=/dev/sda2 ro
}
```

EDIT: Running `update-grub` on the host successfully found the installation, but it still fails to boot with the same Kernel Panic error. I will try rebuilding my kernel to see if there's something I missed in its copnfiguration

Comment: Is your root filesystem on partition or it occupies the whole second hard disk? I.e. is it `sda` or `sda1` ?

Comment: No, I have a 1M partition at the front for the bootloader to hook into (fs type ef02)

Comment: What's your kernel command line? Can you post bootloader configuration?

Comment: That's the grub.cfg file, correct?

Comment: I think yes. [edit](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/288432/edit) your question and include it.

Comment: Also, what is the kernel command line?

Comment: From the LFS Grub page - "From GRUB's perspective, the kernel files are relative to the partition used. If you used a separate /boot partition, remove /boot from the above linux line. You will also need to change the set root line to point to the boot partition." Are you sure your root is on /dev/sda2?

Comment: Yes I am sure. I did not use a separate /boot partition

Comment: And root is /dev/sda2? When you say second hard drive, I strongly suspect that it would be /dev/sdb. Moreover, if both hard drives are on the same system, you should just run `update-grub` in the host system and it will automatically detect LFS on the second hard drive and provide a boot entry for it.

Comment: I am unsure as to if the root is /dev/sda2. I built the system on a second HDD, but it is being booted from a VM where it is the only HDD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know it's been awhile, but in recently rebuilding the LFS project, it is, by default, incompatible with VM booting. The LFS has to be booted as the host lb a physical machine. If anyone can prove me wrong, please do.

Comment: It has now been a while more, but I have been able to pinpoint the cause by trial and error: it is the initramfs. For testing, in my QEMU guest I built a custom kernel and initramfs for LFS, and had Artix Linux installed separately. LFS kernel + LFS initramfs fails, also Artix kernel + LFS initramfs, but LFS kernel + Artix initramfs boots normally.

Comment: To clarify, I boot using syslinux, and LFS boots normally when I specify root=/dev/sdXN, but root=UUID=... and similar forms don't work with LFS initramfs.

Comment: It seems that LFS initramfs errorneously has the init script as /sbin/init (from within the initramfs), instead of the [expected /init](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Custom_Initramfs#Prerequisites). Moving the file with `mv sbin/init .` from with the initramfs source directory and regenerating initramfs fixes the error for me.